# Swift launch waze from webview link

Tags: ios, swift, webview, swift3, uiwebview

I have a webview which is connected to a url, on this url there is a link that when clicked, should open waze with an adress. on safari it works fine but when I try to open it through my webview it doesn't seem to work. is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open the link externally, you'll need to set the `UIWebViewDelegate` for the webview.

Then, implement:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
```

From there, you can grab the `URL` out of the `URLRequest` and open the link externally.

Then, you can call `func open(_ url: URL, options: [String : Any] = [:], completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)` on your `UIApplication` with the `URL` from the webview.

Comment: Hi, first thanks for the response but I didn't quite got it. if I try to open link from a webview how this is comes together? maybe i should add a picture?

Comment: UIWebView won't open open an external link, such as what you're trying to do. You need to implement that method to intercept the navigation action and grab the URL and open it yourself.